# Me pide dos valores al mismo tiempo

Tags: java, poo

tengo un problema, no le puedo introducir un valor por teclado a una variable porque me salen 2 mensajes al mismo tiempo

```
package libro;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //libro1
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite el autor del libro");

        String autor1 = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite el numero de ISNB");

        int ISNB1 = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite el titulo del libro");

        String titulo1 = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite el número de páginas");

        int numPaginas1 = sc.nextInt();

        Libro libro1 = new Libro(ISNB1, titulo1, autor1, numPaginas1);

        System.out.println("LIBRO1");

        System.out.println(libro1); //estado del objeto con metodo toString

    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Buenas una de las soluciones es manejar todo con nextLine() y usar los convertidores de java para obtener otro tipo.Lo que pasa es que el buffer mantiene un \n después de usar el nextInt(), esto también lo puedes solucionar usando un sc.nextLine()(Este obtiene en \n que provoca ese salto) después de obtener un dato númerico.

```
package libro;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //libro1
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite el autor del libro");

    String autor1 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Digite el numero de ISNB");

    int ISNB1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Digite el titulo del libro");

    String titulo1 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Digite el número de páginas");

    int numPaginas1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    Libro libro1 = new Libro(ISNB1, titulo1, autor1, numPaginas1);

    System.out.println("LIBRO1");

    System.out.println(libro1); //estado del objeto con metodo toString

   }

}
```

---------------------------------Versión 2------------------

```
System.out.println("Digite el numero de ISNB");
int ISNB1 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Digite el titulo del libro");

String titulo1 = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Digite el número de páginas");
int numPaginas1 = sc.nextInt();
```